# How can I output a CString variable with std::cout?

Tags: c++, mfc

Code:

```
CString a = "a";
CStringArray arr;
arr.Add(a);

cout << a << endl;
cout << arr[0] << endl;
```

Output:

```
000001E46FEDD8F8
000001E46FEDD8F8
```

Expected output:

```
a
a
```

The output is not the string but an address.

How to output `CString` data instead of outputting it's addresses?

Comment: Call [`GetString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring) on the `CString` instances. If that still outputs the address, use `wcout` instead. Ideally, do not use `CString` at all, but rather the `CStringA` and `CStringW` template instantiations. As it stands, there's no way for us to see what your code actually does.

Comment: What is CString? (maybe it is the old MFC string, or some string you made  up yourself but we can't know) In C++ use `std::string` and `std::wstring` (only convert to other string types on the last possible moment when you need to call some other API). For an array of strings use `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: `CString` was a part of Microsoft's early attempts to embrace and extend C++. It can sometimes be found on display in some historical museum, of some kind. Which very old C+× textbook are you using to learn C++? Does it say anything about `std::string`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The `CStringT` class template has a particular feature you won't find in "modern" string abstractions: It is binary layout compatible with `char const*` or `wchar_t const*`. I wonder how the *"old equals bad"* dogma fares when applied to your favorite kernel.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @IInspectable. I don't recall having any difficulties using `std::string` with C style strings. `std::string` has a very useful `c_str()` method that, guess what, gives me a `const char *`, ditto for `std::wstring`'s which produces a `const wchar_t *`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik If you don't know what I mean, maybe you should not have commented on a subject outside your area of expertise.

Comment: Well, @IInspectable, I'm fairly certain that nobody really knows what you were referring to.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That may be the case. If it were true, there's still the observation to be made that nobody else felt the urge to leave an unhelpful, condescending comment.

Comment: You should not be using a `CStringArray` nowadays. This is two generations before. After it you could use `CString<Array>`. And at the moment you have `std::vector<CString>`, which is what Microsoft themselves are currently recommending to use.

Answer (score 6):

As others have already pointed out you, you can get the behavior you want using a cast. If (for example) you're printing the value out solely for debugging, I suppose that's sufficient--by the time you have the code ready for release, the code with the cast will be long gone, with no hint that it ever existed, so nobody else has to put up with it.

If, however, you plan to write a `CString` to an `iostream` as a normal part of your program's operation, I'd consider it nearly obligatory to write an overload of `operator<<` specifically to do that job, so in the rest of the code you can write: `cout << arr[0] << endl;` as you'd originally intended, and it will work correctly. I'd pop this into a header so you can just include it where needed. This should probably be overloaded for `CStringA` and `CStringW` to work properly with each:

```cpp
#pragma once

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, CStringA const &s) {
    return os << s.GetString(); // or use the cast, if you prefer
}

std::wostream &operator<<(std::wostream &os, CStringW const &s) { 
    return os << s.GetString();
}
```

Depending on your needs, you could add overloads to write a `CStringW` to a narrow stream and/or a `CStringA` to a wide stream as well.

Answer (score 3):

`operator<<` has a lot of different overloads.  If more than one would fit in a given context, the compiler has rules for choosing the best fit.  In this case it chose to give you the address of the object rather than the contents of the string.

One of the handiest properties of `CString` is that it will implicitly cast to a pointer to an array of const characters.  You say a "strong conversion" didn't work, but did you do it right?

```
cout << static_cast<const char *>(a) << endl;
```

Note that `CString` isn't a single class; it's a macro expanding to `CStringA` or `CStringW` depending on your compiler settings, whether you've configured to use narrow strings or wide (Unicode) strings.  You can avoid some surprises if you explicitly use the `A` or `W` variant directly instead of letting the compiler choose it for you.

As for whether you should even be using `CString` in this day and age, that's more complicated.  It was invented for use in Microsoft's MFC and ATL frameworks, and if you're still using one of those you probably won't be able to get away from it.  I was in such a situation as recently as 3 years ago.  I believe it's even older than `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

Comment: Yes, CString was first released with Microsoft C/C++ 7.0 (along with MFC 1.0) in 1992.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for that nugget of information.  The STL where std::string originated didn't get invented until 1993, and was incorporated into C++ in 1994.

Comment: @MarkRansom actually `CString` it's not a macro but a template based class defined as `typedef ATL::CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitMFC< TCHAR > > CString;`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thanks for looking that up.  I don't know if I was remembering a very old implementation, or just assuming it was a macro like the rest of the Microsoft A/W split.

Comment: @MarkRansom yep, I think you're right, that the very early implementations of `CString` were defined as macros, I might remember something like this from the very old days, but maybe it's also a false memory...

Comment: MFC's `CString` used to be a preprocessor symbol at some point, but is a type alias now. As I recollect, this was a corollary of merging ATL's and MFC's `CString` "types". Whether `CString` is a preprocessor symbol or a type alias for a class template parameterized on a preprocessor symbol doesn't change a whole lot. When you see `CString` in code you just don't know what type it is.

Comment: @IInspectable I started using CString before ATL existed, so that explains how I came about my belief that it was a macro.

Comment: @MarkRansom Just a detail, but `std::string` predates STL (and originally wasn't a template). When the STL was added to the standard, the string class which was already in the draft was "STLized", with iterators and all. Some of the C++ compilers had already implemented the earlier version, and the reason you find a number of functions, like `std::string::find` (instead of expecting people to use `std::find` with iterators) is to avoid breaking existing code.

Comment: That's also why the `std::string` member functions use (start, length), rather than the open interval [begin, end) which is omnipresent in the STL.

Comment: @JamesKanze no less a luminary than Herb Sutter considers `std::string` to be poorly designed: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm

Comment: @MarkRansom I certainly agree with him about that, although I would have said "not designed" instead of poorly designed. (I'd also argue that it isn't an abstraction of a string, but rather than an array of `char_type`. But then, in my career, I've had to deal a lot with accented characters in many different encodings.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Hey James, nice to see you around again--it's been a long time. I'm still hoping for a library to make string manipulation at least half as convenient as SNOBOL 4 was 40+ years ago. None in sight yet though...

Comment: @JerryCoffin then why don't you write it yourself?  I used SNOBOL only once, 40+ years ago, for a class assignment.  Can't remember a thing about it now.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I sort of tried once, but never found a set of operator overloads that really worked out as a close enough imitation of SNOBOL's syntax to get even sort of close to the same "feel" (though it's pretty easy to at least get a little closer than `std::string` provides).

Answer (score 0):

Since `CString` is used, it has to be `GetString()`. This method retrieves the character string associated with the object (a pointer to a null-terminated character string).

```cpp
CString a = "a";
CStringArray arr;
arr.Add(a);

// If CString happens to be CStringA:
std::cout << a.GetString() << std::endl;
std::cout << arr[0].GetString() << std::endl;

// If CString happens to be CStringW (Default):
std::wcout << a.GetString() << std::endl;
std::wcout << arr[0].GetString() << std::endl;
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=msvc-170